# Integrating xPDF in an IOS? (feasibility checking)

Tags: iphone, python, ios, pdf

I am developing App in which PDF text searching & highlighting is needed. I found like its very difficult to highlight in PDF. So i thought to convert PDF to HTML then by using java-script, Search the string & Highlight it. Actually i got success in searching & highlighting on HTML text using java script.If any1 need **source code** send your email id. 
   But my obstacle is PDF to HTML conversion. I know it is very hard,bcoz PDF is enrich text & HTML doesn't support all the features. In between i got some source code in Python i.e. PDFMiner. With out jail breaking its hard to use Python in IOS. So i dropped this idea also.

**Now i m looking on xPDF, its C++ based code to convert PDF to HTML. Did any1 got success over integrating xPDF into your IOS app. I want to know feasibility of this.**

Thanks in advance for ur thoughtful reply,

Naveen Thunga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find an example. Still has some problems, but is a good start:

https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten

Comment: I downloaded it. But when i execute it nothing is displaying.

Comment: Please include some information in the answer itself, in case the link goes dead, and so people don't have to follow the link to know what it is.